# How to view contents of `items` parameter for Firebase Ecommerce events

Tags: android, firebase, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I have an Android app linked to a firebase project that fires the `FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE` event with the `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS` set to an array of bundles, as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ecommerce).

I can see the items being sent in logcat if I turn on Firebase Logging, but I can't work out how to view the items in Firebase itself. How can I see them?

I can see the `PURCHASE` event in Firebase, but the items parameter doesn't show.

I'm not using this parameter in any other events.

I'm using a GTM container if that's relevant.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to see the items of a list (Not 100% sure), but if it suits your case, you can go for purchases by single items.

Comment: And then just attach the individual item properties to each purchase event?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do the job:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID , "Item ID");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME , "Item Name");
bundle.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE , ItemPrice);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY , "Item Category");
mAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE , bundle);
```

Hope it works out!

Comment: Yeah this is definitely a possibility although I'm trying to avoid having to do an event for every single item.

Comment: If there's no other way (which I don't seem to find), either you have to change your requirements or have to do a bit of extra work(as in my answer). It's up to you :-).

Comment: If it helped, kindly mark it as correct. I would appreciate that 8-)

Comment: Yeah, I was aware this was a possibility before asking this question, and was trying to avoid having to do this really.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will not be able to see the items in the debug view, but if everything is configured correctly they will arrive correctly at GTM.

I recommed you to check if items are properly sent in android studio's logcat.